# Getting exec bad access error in mapView regionDidChangeAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am using showAnnotations method to show my markers on `MKMapView` in iOS7 .Sometimes it works perfectly and show all annotation but sometimes it give `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Here is my code.

```
NSArray *annotations = MapView.annotations;
_mapNeedsPadding = YES;
[MapView showAnnotations:annotations animated:YES];

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    if(_mapNeedsPadding){
        [mapView setVisibleMapRect:mapView.visibleMapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 20, 10, 10) animated:YES];
        _mapNeedsPadding = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up the delegates correctly? Are you using a strong reference properly? `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is generally an indication that you're trying to reference a deallocated instance.

Comment: I am using a strong reference property and i properly connected my MkMapView object with xib.Delegates are set properly that why it is calling mapView regiondidchangeanimated delegate.I donot know what is a problem

Comment: Does the problem occur after you've done some other navigating between view controllers?

Comment: yes this problem occur only when i move from one view controller to another.during navigating i am loading my mkmapview to search stations

Comment: Are you trying to use the same instance in more than one? If so, try setting the delegate methods in your navigation controller instead.

Comment: I am using a same instance of a mkmapview.Whenever i want to search anything i enter station in one view controller and based on station keyword it will open in another view controller

Comment: Ah.. You can't do that. You either need to use a shared instance (singleton) - a recommended approach, or create a new instance each time you need it

Comment: No i tried to create a new omstance of mkmapView but again it is sending a same error.

Comment: Ok then you need to create a singleton class - look up "how to create share instance of class"

Comment: ok i will see.Thanx alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code shown, you are getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because calling `setVisibleMapRect` causes `regionDidChangeAnimated` to be called by the map view again which starts an infinite recursion.

Even though you are using the boolean flag `_mapNeedsPadding` to possibly prevent this recursion, the problem is that the flag is being set to `NO` *after* `setVisibleMapRect` has already been called (and it has *already* called `regionDidChangeAnimated` and the flag never gets set to `NO`).

So your code calls `setVisibleMapRect` which causes `regionDidChangeAnimated` to get called again resulting in infinite recursion resulting in stack overflow resulting in `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

The "quick fix" is to set `_mapNeedsPadding` *before* calling `setVisibleMapRect`:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    if(_mapNeedsPadding){
        _mapNeedsPadding = NO; // <-- call BEFORE setVisibleMapRect
        [mapView setVisibleMapRect:mapView.visibleMapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 20, 10, 10) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**However, I don't recommend this approach to begin with.**

Instead, you should manually calculate an `MKMapRect` based on the annotations you want to show and call `setVisibleMapRect:edgePadding:animated:` from the main code (instead of `showAnnotations:animated:`).

And, *don't implement or do anything in `regionDidChangeAnimated`*.

Example:

```
NSArray *annotations = MapView.annotations;
//_mapNeedsPadding = YES;
//[MapView showAnnotations:annotations animated:YES];

MKMapRect rectForAnns = MKMapRectNull;
for (id<MKAnnotation> ann in annotations)
{
    MKMapPoint annPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(ann.coordinate);

    MKMapRect annRect = MKMapRectMake(annPoint.x, annPoint.y, 1, 1);

    if (MKMapRectIsNull(rectForAnns))
        rectForAnns = annRect;
    else
        rectForAnns = MKMapRectUnion(rectForAnns, annRect);
}

UIEdgeInsets rectInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 20, 10, 10);

[MapView setVisibleMapRect:rectForAnns edgePadding:rectInsets animated:YES];


//Do NOT implement regionDidChangeAnimated...
//- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
//    if(_mapNeedsPadding){
//        [mapView setVisibleMapRect:mapView.visibleMapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 20, 10, 10) animated:YES];
//        _mapNeedsPadding = NO;
//    }
//}
```